# Index_slicing_problem

Tags: python, visual-studio, slice

I have started learning Python today and I am facing a problem while doing "slice" in Python. I saw Brocod's video but after following him the problem wasn't solved.

```
website="http//google.com"
slice=slice(7,-4)
print(website[slice])
```

**And The output I am getting**:

```
[Running] python -u "d:\Learning\BroCode\Python\String_slice.py"
oogle

[Done] exited with code=0 in 0.505 seconds
```

I tried to rewrite the code, reinstalling Vs code but none of them worked.

Comment: what do you want to achieve? get a slice of `"http://google.com"`? to do so, use `[start:end]` notation. e.g. `a = 'https://google.com'; a[6:15]`

Comment: I just want to separate the "google" from the string and print as an output

Comment: You seem to have a typo your URL (missing ":"), otherwise it would work.

Answer (score 1):

Read the doc carefully : https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/slice

Your string index starts from 0 so `g` is the 7th index, which is 6.

You should do :

```
website="http//google.com"
slice=slice(6,-4)
print(website[slice])
```

to get `google`